# Throttling writes to ES from Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, throttling

In our project, we are using Apache Spark to write to ES. We run multiple spark jobs that write to ES parallelly. The data volume we are dealing with too big and resulting in write throughput as high as ~5K write/sec.

We want to throttle our ES writes so as to bring it down to 500 to 1000 write/sec range. We have come across ES configs like `es.batch.size.bytes` and `es.batch.size.entries` but we are not sure how these configs can work with Apache Spark.

Comment: Kindly review the answer to the question and mark as answer if it solved your issue. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Repartitioning your data in Spark using either `repartition()`, or more preferably `coalesce()` if you are lowering the number of partitions, is a simple way to throttle the rate of indexing to ES.

If you want to set the property in pyspark

```
esconf={}
esconf["es.mapping.id"] = "_id"
esconf["es.nodes"] = "localhost"
esconf["es.port"] = "9200"
esconf["es.batch.size.bytes"] = "1000000" //default 1mb for bulk request
esconf["es.batch.size.entries"] = "1000" //default 1000 for bulk request
```

```
df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").options(**esconf).mode("append").save("index_name")
```

Note: Note the bulk size and entries are allocated per task instance. Always multiply by the number of tasks within a Hadoop job to get the total bulk size/entries at runtime hitting Elasticsearch. This is the reason you are getting 5K write/s